# How to know inside a class, what is the object is working on?

Tags: python, class

I don't know if this is possible, but let me explain what I try to achieve (in Python):

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, pos, vel):
        self.pos = pos
        self.vel = vel
    def __str__(self):
        #I want to know here if it is either Sedan or Sport
        if Sedan:
           print "Sedan"
        elif Sport 
           print "Sport"
        else:
           print "unknown"

Sedan = Vehicle( pos1, vel1)
Sport = vehicle( pos2, vel2)

print Sedan
```

Note: I just use method: `__str__` as example, but it can be any other method I define inside the class.

The point is that I want to execute some code inside the class definition depending on the instance that was created. I don't know if it possible what I am trying to do, or if there is a way to know inside the class what instance is working on, or this is just crazy.

Comment: Perhaps you should create `Sedan` and `Sport` subclasses of the abstract `Vehicle` class, each of which overrides the `__str__` method. By the way, `__str__` should return a string, not print one.

Comment: It sounds like you either want to subclass `Vehicle`, so you can do `sedan = Sedan(pos1, vel1)` or provide the type of vehicle as a parameter to the `Vehicle` constructor.

Comment: Now create a list of vehicles: `fleet = [Vehicle(pos1, vel1), Vehicle(pos2, vel2)]`. What names do these have? What if I created 5 copies of this list?

Answer (score 3):

What you want is not possible (nor does it make sense). A class (or a function) cannot "know" the names of the variables located somewhere else. What you describe (execute some code depending on the context) is a typical use case for inheritance. So, to add context-dependent code, just extend your base class

```
class Sedan(Vehicle):
    def __str__(self):
      return "Sedan"

class Sport(Vehicle):
    def __str__(self):
      return "Sport"
```

Comment: Well, thanks for your comment, although the method __ str__ used as an example to explain simply what I want to do, of course, what I'm trying to do is run other codes depending on the instance referred to. Anyway, I appreciate your idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would pass something like `kind` through `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, pos, vel, kind):
    self.pos = pos
    self.vel = vel
    self.kind = kind

    def __str__(self):
        print(self.kind)
```

Though, in Python, `__str__` should `return`, not `print`.

I.e.:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.kind
```

Comment: Well, thanks for your comment, although the method __ str__ used as an example to explain simply what I want to do, of course, what I'm trying to do is run other codes depending on the instance referred to. Anyway, I appreciate your idea.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, names (like `Sedan` in your example) are just references to objects. If you are relying on the references a variable has for functionality, you are probably doing it wrong.

Consider this simple example:

```
sedan = Vehicle(...)
sport = Vehicle(...)
cars = [sedan, sport]
for car in cars:
    print(car)
```

Now each `Vehicle` has multiple references - the first is accessible via `sedan` and `cars[0]` and, inside the first iteration of the `for` loop, `car`. In `__str__`, which reference should be used?

It is much, much better to make the data needed for the class instances to work explicit, for example:

```
class Vehicle:

    def __init__(self, pos, vel, type_=None):
        self.pos = pos
        self.vel = vel
        self.type_ = type_

    def __str__(self):
        return "unknown" if self.type_ is None else self.type_             

sedan = Vehicle(pos1, vel1, "sedan")
```

Alternatively, if there will be more fundamental differences between the two types of `Vehicle` (e.g. different attributes, rather than just different values for the attributes), consider inheritance:

```
class Sedan(Vehicle):

    def __str__(self):
        return "sedan"
```

Comment: Well, thanks for your comment, although the method __ str__ used as an example to explain simply what I want to do, of course, what I'm trying to do is run other codes depending on the instance referred to. Anyway, I appreciate your idea.

Comment: @froycard the answer still stands - relying on the references to the object for functionality is neither wise nor Pythonic.